# Animation when object is in viewport doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, viewport

I wanted to add some magic to my project and tried to use 
code from this tutorial https://codepen.io/charkins/pen/XmVRvr but it works only on this codepen. I even copied the same code to  another codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qxROQX  and it doesn't work.
I don't know jquery that much, I would really appreciate little bit of help

Here's JS file, it's suppposed to detect if element is in viewport and then apply animation to it

```
//need to rewrite in prototype
//no jquery

$(function() {
  var $blocks = $('.animBlock.notViewed');
  var $window = $(window);

  $window.on('scroll', function(e){
    $blocks.each(function(i,elem){
      if($(this).hasClass('viewed')) 
        return;

      isScrolledIntoView($(this));
    });
  });
});

function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
  var elemOffset = 0;

  if(elem.data('offset') != undefined) {
    elemOffset = elem.data('offset');
  }
  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

  if(elemOffset != 0) { // custom offset is updated based on scrolling direction
    if(docViewTop - elemTop >= 0) {
      // scrolling up from bottom
      elemTop = $(elem).offset().top + elemOffset;
    } else {
      // scrolling down from top
      elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height() - elemOffset
    }
  }

  if((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop)) {
    // once an element is visible exchange the classes
    $(elem).removeClass('notViewed').addClass('viewed');

    var animElemsLeft = $('.animBlock.notViewed').length;
    if(animElemsLeft == 0){
      // with no animated elements left debind the scroll event
      $(window).off('scroll');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Look at your browser console: `pen.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` it's all there, you are just missing jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have to include jquery.min.js in your codepen. For that**

Go to codepen > settings > javascript > add external scripts

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/master/src/prototype.js
```

I have imported jquery to code and now its working fine.

**DEMO**

```js
//need to rewrite in prototype
//no jquery

$(function() {
  var $blocks = $('.animBlock.notViewed');
  var $window = $(window);

  $window.on('scroll', function(e){
    $blocks.each(function(i,elem){
      if($(this).hasClass('viewed')) 
        return;
        
      isScrolledIntoView($(this));
    });
  });
});

function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
  var elemOffset = 0;
  
  if(elem.data('offset') != undefined) {
    elemOffset = elem.data('offset');
  }
  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
  
  if(elemOffset != 0) { // custom offset is updated based on scrolling direction
    if(docViewTop - elemTop >= 0) {
      // scrolling up from bottom
      elemTop = $(elem).offset().top + elemOffset;
    } else {
      // scrolling down from top
      elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height() - elemOffset
    }
  }
  
  if((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop)) {
    // once an element is visible exchange the classes
    $(elem).removeClass('notViewed').addClass('viewed');
    
    var animElemsLeft = $('.animBlock.notViewed').length;
    if(animElemsLeft == 0){
      // with no animated elements left debind the scroll event
      $(window).off('scroll');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body{ height:1000px; width:auto;}

.block { 
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background-color:orange;
  margin-top:50px;
}

.animBlock {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all .55s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all .55s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all .55s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .55s ease-in;
  transition: all .55s ease-in;
}
.animBlock[data-position="left"] { left: -20%; }
.animBlock[data-position="right"] { right: -20%; }
.animBlock[data-position="top"] { top: -20%;}
.animBlock[data-position="bottom"] { bottom: -20%;}

.animBlock[data-position="left"].viewed {
  left: 0%;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
.animBlock[data-position="right"].viewed {
  right: 0%;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
.animBlock[data-position="top"].viewed {
  top: 0%;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
.animBlock[data-position="bottom"].viewed {
  bottom: 0%;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Author: Cory Harkins -->

<h1>This is a test of concept, scroll down...</h1>

<div data-position="left" data-offset="60" class="notViewed animBlock">
  <div class="block">in from left</div>
</div>


<div data-position="right" data-offset="60" class="notViewed animBlock">
  <div class="block">in from right</div>
</div>
<!-- decreased the offsett here so square doesn't float in so quick-->
<div data-position="top" data-offset="0" class="notViewed animBlock">
  <div class="block">in from top</div>
</div>
<!-- increased the offsett here so there isn't such a lag as it floats upwards-->
<div data-position="bottom" data-offset="300" class="notViewed animBlock">
  <div class="block">in from bottom</div>
</div>

<div data-position="left" data-offset="60" class="notViewed animBlock">
  <div class="block">
    <h1>Refresh to restart the animations</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```